# AngularJS Access object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When in AngularJS

I write the following `Edit {{locations}} Home`

It shows as  `Edit [{"title":"Hello","gps":"1"}] Home`

When I try `Edit {{locations.title}} Home`

It shows as  `Edit Home`

What would I need to do in order to get it to show as `Edit Hello Home`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says nothing because your locations is an array. So access it like this `{{locations[0].title}}`.